# What is the proper verb for "doing" an integral?

Tags: calculus, test-design, terminology

It's time to write exams, and when writing in committee we often discover differences in usage between various instructors.  Here's an example I noticed today.

What is the proper verb to use in a question of the form: "____ the following integrals"?  I've seen *evaluate*, *compute*, *solve*, and others.

Comment: In Russian, there is a specific verb for integrals, and it is, amusingly, "take". Uncomputable integrals are, therefore, named "untakeable" :-)

Comment: Personally I either find, calculate or integrate them (I might '*find this integral*' or '*integrate that term*' for example). I also compute or evaluate integrals, particularly definite integrals. I *never* solve them, unless they're written as an *equation* involving some unknown (in which case, it's actually the equation that's being solved for the unknown).

Comment: I proctored some exams this week. A student raised her hand and asked, "what does *evaluate* mean?" I said "*solve*" and thought about this question at MESE.

Comment: I think I would have said, "*do*" which is how I got here in the first place. :-)

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/830677/77144

Comment: @OrcJMR what word did you have in mind? I thought it was проинтегрировать, which is not "take".

Comment: @KCd I meant "взять интеграл", "неберущиеся интегралы". The verb "интегрировать" means "to integrate", applying to another object (a function).

Comment: @OrcJMR [My English language](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4721742/can-one-say-take-an-integral-instead-of-the-usual-calculate-an-integral-wha) and [Mathematics](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/608960/can-one-say-take-an-integral-instead-of-calculate-an-integral-what-other-op) SE questions on this topic (before I directed to this one):

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I'm no native English speaker, but you can tackle that question from the mathematical point of view as well.

The best verb depends on how you view the nature of definite and indefinite integrals.

### Operators/Functionals

Indefinite integrals are operators mapping functions to a set of functions or function (as representative of the equivalence class).

Definite integrals are operators mapping functions to numbers for given intervalls or operators mapping numbers (as one boundary) to numbers for given function and other boundary. In that case, it's numbervalued function of numbers.

Consequently, you should use `evaluate`.

### Items of a special calculus named "calculus"

The theory ["calculus"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calculus) is a special [calculus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calculus_%28disambiguation%29). Consequently, you should use `calculate`, even for indefinite integrals.

### Problems

If you see integrals as problems, which non-computable integrals or integrals difficult to compute are indeed, then you should use `find`.

### Differential equations

Regard the differential equation $\frac{\mathrm{d}F(x)}{\mathrm{d}x}=f(x)$ to be solved for $F(x)$. Its solution is $F(x)=\int f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x$ (or $\{F(x)\}=\int f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x$).

#### As solution

If you regard the integral as that solution, you should use the verb associated to solutions of algebraic equations: `find`.

#### As equation itself

If you regard the integral as the equation itself, you should use the verb associated to (algebraic) equations: `solve`.

Comment: This answer uses English better and is both better explained and justified than mine. +1. Your reasoning I'd use _solve $dy/dx=x\sin x$_, but still can't bring myself to solve $\int x \sin x dx$. Your introduction of _calculate_ is very good - this is a strong word to use. I often find non-native speakers have thought about language more clearly than I have!

Comment: I would quibble that the indefinite integral maps functions *to* functions, not *onto* functions.  But I like the mathematical approach!  Can you explain the Problems perspective? I can't parse your sentence there.

Comment: @MatthewLeingang 1. I have language difficulties with the correct prepositions of `to map`. If it should be `to` instead of `onto`, I'll change it. 2. Take the example $\int\frac{\sin x}{x}\mathrm{d}x$ for someone who doesn't know the sine integral function yet. It's not a simple calculation/operation to *determine* the integral, as all usual approaches fail. So, this is a real problem, whose solution needs to be *found*. The less you know about integrals, the more integrands are problematic. So, one could think, that integrals are problematic in general, with many of them already solved.

Comment: @MatthewLeingang I think what AndrewC may be saying (which I agree with) is that one can only solve an _equation_, and $\int f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x$ is not an equation. So one shouldn't say "solve $\int f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x$." However you could rephrase it as "solve $\int f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x=F(x)$ for $F(x)$" which represents the same mathematical problem. (oh wait, I just realized this wasn't what you were asking in your comment, but I'll leave this comment here for posterity)

Comment: @DavidZ So it should rather be "If you see $\int f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x$ as the *solution* of the differential equation …"?

Comment: @Toscho well one could say that, but even if you do, I still don't think the verb "solve" seems appropriate. If $\int f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x$ is identified as the solution of the differential equation, then the word I would use is "evaluate" or "find" or perhaps (but not likely) "simplify". After all, a solution isn't something you can solve either.

Comment: @DavidZ Agreed.

Comment: @Toscho: Some people use *onto* as an adjective synonymous with *surjective*.  ("A bijection is a map which is both one-to-one and onto.") For that reason, I only use the preposition *onto* for surjective maps.  So yes, I think it's clearer to say *to*.

Answer (score 15):

I would avoid the verb *solve* as I reserve this for things like equations, inequalities and problems. An integral is equal to a number or a function, so verbs like *find*, *evaluate* etc are more appropriate.

I'd use *compute* only for numerical integration methods.

*evaluate* and *find* are the two verbs that are used in textbooks and exams that I've come across. I think *evaluate* is better for a definite integral because the result is a number, and *find* is OK for both, eg

*Find $\int \sin x e^{\cos x}dx$*
or
*Find the value of $\int _1^\infty \frac 1 {x^2} dx$*
or
*Evaluate $\int _2^5 x(2x+1)\sin x dx$*

Comment: I prefer *evaluate* as *find* makes me thing the answer is under my couch, misplaced somewhere.

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer That made me laugh! Evaluate is correct and good formal language.

Comment: I personally would use compute for determining any sort of integral in a calc class outside of a theoretical context. That's what you are doing anyways tough I could see the desire for a more specific term for when doing numerics. However, I'd probably use the term "numerically compute".

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer That's what it sometimes feels like to me - the answer is somewhere nearby but I haven't quite located it yet, so I find the usage of *find* for integrals quite apt.

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer I am reminded of a certain flippant answer that made it's way onto a [t-shirt](http://www.catalogclassics.com/classics/Tees-Sweatshirts_1BA/View-All-T-Shirts-Sweatshirts_1BB/Item_s-3-FIND-X-SWEATSHIRT_CG8431S.html).

Answer (score 11):

I usually phrase it as "Determine $\int x^2\ dx$" or "Determine $\int_1^3 x^2\ dx$". This way

1) it doesn't tip them off to what type of answer they should arrive at, and

2) it allows them to read the symbol $\int$ as either "integral" or (better in my opinion) "antiderivative".

For completeness, in some problems I write "Set-up, but do not evaluate, the integral that computes some geometrical/physical thing." But when I actually want them to perform the integration (which is another phrase I use colloquially but never as instructions) and arrive at an answer, I write "Use integration to find the geometrical/physical thing."

Comment: Could you explain how *determine* is better than *find* or *evaluate* in 2?  I mean, do other choices preclude them from reading the integral sign as "antiderivative"?

Comment: Personally I think of "evaluate" as resulting in a numerical value. And for me "find" is more appropriate for the setting up of formulas/equations. My point in 2) was that I avoid using the word "integral" in the way that the OP used it.

Comment: @MatthewLeingang `determine` is completely general. It doesn't say anything about the nature of the integral and doesn't fix any way of solution. In that case, you need to accept, if students *guess* the integral somehow and proof it by its derivative.

Answer (score 7):

The proper verb is whatever verb your textbook uses.

This helped me one time when I wrote "Evaluate this integral", and one student approximated the integral using rectangles. I was able to show the student that every problem I assigned from the textbook that required a symbolic answer said "Evaluate this integral" whereas every problem that required a numerical approximation said "Approximate this integral". The student did not argue.

This is a good policy for any exam problem, not just integrals. I always use the same phrasing on exams that my textbook uses.

Comment: This is a good point. At my place of work our calculus courses are coordinated with several instructors but the same final. I push for consistency with textbook notation, not because it's best, but because it's common.

Answer (score 4):

From a general test writing standpoint:
If you and the students both know that the problems are to be solved by integrating a formula, why not "Integrate the following..."  If they have to figure out whether to use integration or some other calculus then that won't work.

In practical applications, such as HPLC analysis, the usual instruction is calculate the amount of substance X by integrating the peak area in the chromatogram in comparison to a standard chromatogram